# I have an textview that overflows no matter what parameters I give it

Tags: android

It's a textview that could possibly have long text in side it. it over flows and pushes half of ratings bar off the screen.

How can I make it cut the text and not push the ratingsbar off?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rest_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="long text goes goes here long text goes goes here long text goes goes here"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/myRatingBar"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:numStars="5" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could check the length of the string and if it is greater than a set length and do something like`...` at the end of the string

but you are setting the textview to `wrap_context` you could also just make it a hard width so it wont change

Answer (score 0):

you can use the  following attribute in your text view

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/myRatingBar"
```

you can also give a specific width to your textview in xml

```
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

and also you can use   the following attribute to limit the length of text view

```
android:maxLength=""
```

Comment: theyre not inside a relativelayout

Comment: i have edited my answer you can limit the length of text view

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:maxLines="1"`. This will cut the text in the TextView if it is long and will not push the Ratings off.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have set the `android:layout_weight="1"` to both views, then I think you can do `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

This will make both views have the same width which is half the parent's width. Or you could modify the weight field according to whatever value you want.